# How do I know which git authentication method is being used?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to verify through which way I'm authenticating to Azure DevOps?

- Am I authenticating through my SSH key?
- Am I authenticating through Azure CLI?
- Am I authenticating through Azure Account extension in VSCode?

Answer (score 5):

For git authentication with Azure DevOps, the first thing I'd do is to run

```
git remote show origin
```

If the Fetch and Push URLs start with `git:`, you're using an SSH key. If it starts with `https:`, it's going to do an OAuth browser login to Azure DevOps, and then display a message telling you that you're signed in and can close the browser window, at which point Git will have the credential it needs to work with the remote repository. In my experience, it works the same way in VS Code - it uses whatever credential the Git application has negotiated.

The Azure CLI should not come into play with Git - it can be used to manipulate Azure DevOps features, but does not participate directly in the source control process (other than allowing things like PR submission, etc.)

Comment: Interestingly this answer fixed `authentication error failures` for me. It started happening when I had updated my network credentials. When I ran `git remote show origin`, it authenticated me by asking for the username and password. I entered my new password. Now I am all set!

Answer (score 5):

I found setting `GIT_TRACE=1` to be useful for debugging Git. (I found that from [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/04099e0f7458664b644123405ce14cb396dfecb9/docs/environment.md).)

`git config --list --show-origin` will also show if you're configured to use any `credential.helper` such as Git Credential Manager Core.