Push to private GitHub repo without Token is not blocked
I've created a private GitHub repo.
Per my understanding, only users with access to this private repo will be able to push/pull files to this repo.
I've created an access token to be used for accessing this private repo.
Still I cannot figure out why I am able to push code from an EC2 machine to this private GitHub repo without using the Token.
There are no SSH keys associated with my GitHub account.
How do I check the GitHub credentials cached on my environment?
The command git config --global credential.helper cache does not return anything.
VS Code (remote SSH connection)

Amazon EC2 console

Please find below some details about the git commands used:
For installing Git on EC2 on Amazon Linux, I am using:
dnf install git -y

For setting up the Git, I am using the following commands:
git config --global user.name "XXX"
git config --global user.email "XXX@XXX.XXX"

Where, the name and email are the ones I am using at my GitHub repo.
For pushing the first commit, I am using the following:
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git 
git push -u origin main

Thank you for your support !!


Are you sure it's private repo and you do not have any additional login info on server? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372483/how-do-i-know-which-git-authentication-method-is-being-used

What's the full URL to git repo?

Hi @Justinas
I am sure that I configured a private repo, see:
https://github.com/nirgluzman/clarusway-project208-postgresql
https://github.com/nirgluzman/clarusway-project208-nodejs
https://github.com/nirgluzman/clarusway-project208-react
